# Trying to print a string character by character with delay between two character print

Tags: string, applet

I've tried with code below. please guide me where i am wrong??? The desired output is like..
m(delay)e(delay)s(delay)s(delay)a(delay)g(delay)e.

```
import java.util.*;    
import java.applet.*;    
import java.awt.*;    

/*<applet code="MessageWithDelay" width=400 height=200>
</applet>*/

public class MessageWithDelay extends Applet implements Runnable {
Thread t;
//char msg[] ={"m","e","s","s","a","g","e"};
String str = "message";
Graphics bufferg;
Image buffer;
int counter=0,x=str.length(),i=0;;

    public void init() {

            //initializa the thread
            t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();

            Dimension d = getSize();
            buffer = createImage(d.width,d.height);

            }

    public void run() {

        try {
            while(true)
            {
            //requesting repaint
            repaint();
            if(counter==x)
            {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                    counter=0;
                    i=0;
            }
            else
            {
                    Thread.sleep(400);
            }
            }
            }
         catch(Exception e) {
         }
            }

    public void update(Graphics g) {
    paint(g);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

      if(bufferg == null) {

      Dimension d = getSize();
      bufferg.setColor(Color.green);

            g.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS",Font.BOLD,36));


            bufferg.drawString(str.charAt(i)+"",20,20);
            counter++;
            i+=1;
       //update screen
       g.drawImage(buffer,0,0,this);




       }
   }

}
```

I am working on command prompt and its giving me bunch of different errors. I want to know why the errors occurring if anyone could explain me by trying it. Thanx in advance.

Comment: I have no time to test your code. Please share your errors with us so we can help.

Comment: @Lajos Arpad thank you for replying so early.As i said it is giving me bunch of errors and I am legging in rep points to post the image.I can email you if u think I am asking appropriate.

Comment: NAPSTER, I would gladly help you, but it seems that Gilbert Le Blanc has tested your code, maybe his answer will be useful.

Comment: Yes @LajosArpad... The code modificaton by Gilbert le Blanc worked. thanx for giving ur time.

Comment: Then please, accept his answer, so in the future other people having a similar problem will know that is the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems I found include:

- Use JApplet instead of Applet.
- In the init method, create the buffer before starting the thread.
- Update the buffer with the letters in the run method.  The paint method just paints.  No calculations.

Here's the working code.  I formatted the code in [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org), an integrated development environment (IDE) for Java development.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

/*<applet code="MessageWithDelay" width=400 height=200>
 </applet>*/

public class MessageWithDelay extends JApplet implements Runnable {
    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1722008447683646619L;

    Thread      t;
    String      str = "message";
    Image       buffer;

    @Override
    public void init() {

        Dimension d = getSize();
        buffer = createImage(d.width, d.height);

        // Initialize the thread
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int x = 40;
        int y = 40;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            Graphics g = buffer.getGraphics();
            g.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 36));
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.drawString("" + str.charAt(i), x, y);
            g.dispose();
            x += 40;
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g) {
        paint(g);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, this);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you @GilbertLeBlanc... your modification worked... I would like to know about the occurence of errors IF you would like to explain.

Comment: @NAPSTER: I don't understand your statement.  You arranged code wrongly, and generated errors.  I guess you could run your code through the Eclipse Java debugger, and see which statements generated which errors.  I didn't bother to track down the errors, because there were so many.  I just arranged the code correctly, so it would execute properly.

Comment: dats it @GilbertLeBlanc... U've just answered it. the disarrangement of the code caused error by executing... Thanx